# php refresh after submit

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to PHP and I'm still a learner! and I have a problem with this project:
I'm creating a page that keeps my favorite websites, and I use the GET method to send the Title, URL and Logo of the website to the server and after submitting the variables go in the URL of the page. and because of that, after submitting, each time I refresh the page it adds the previous link to the server. (because the variables are still in the URL)
How can I fix that please help?

```
if(isset($_GET['Add'])){
    $title = $_GET['Title'];
    $url = $_GET['Url'];
    $logo = $_GET['Logo'];
    if(strlen($logo) > 0){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO links (title, url, logo) VALUE ("'.$title.'", "'.$url.'", "Icons/'.$logo.'");';
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    } else{
        $logo = 'DefaultIcon.png';
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO links (title, url, logo) VALUE ("'.$title.'", "'.$url.'", "Icons/'.$logo.'");';
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    }

}
```

How can I clear the URL from variables after submitting?

Comment: Before inserting into table you may test if that item is already in the database or you may create an unique index on that db table column

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect when row successfully added.
And actually you need to read about [`mysqli::prepared`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) - it can keep your site from SQL injections.

Probably you need to read about a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) - sometimes you can use it to make your code less.

For example - your code with a ternary operator can look like that:

```
if(isset($_GET['Add'])){
    $title = $_GET['Title'];
    $url = $_GET['Url'];
    $logo = $_GET['Logo'] ? : 'DefaultIcon.png'; // this is a ternary operator.
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO links (title, url, logo) VALUE ("'.$title.'", "'.$url.'", "Icons/'.$logo.'");';
    if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql) === true) {
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // your redirect can be look that.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple like this Refresh the page after submitting

```
    if( mysqli_query($connect, $sql) )
    {
      header("Location: your pace link here");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect it to your success page in order to remove the data's inputed.

something like this....

```
    if(isset($_GET['Add'])){
    $title = $_GET['Title'];
    $url = $_GET['Url'];
    $logo = $_GET['Logo'];
    if(strlen($logo) > 0){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO links (title, url, logo) VALUE ("'.$title.'", "'.$url.'",
                "Icons/'.$logo.'");';
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
         header('location: success.php'); //rename it to your success page.
    }

}
```